# Looking to get number of real time users from Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, real-time-data

I would like to get the real-time user number from Google Analytics Real-time Overview page. I have looked into react-ga but it doesn't seem to have what I am looking for.

I have followed the guide below, but my GET requests have not gone through in my app
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/reference

If someone could be so kind to give an example using React.

Below is the API call portion of my code. I have already implemented Google Sign In and is currently signed in.

```
window.gapi.client
        .request({
          path:
            'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/realtime/ids=ga%3A(my_id)&metrics=rt%3AactiveUsers&dimensions=rt%3Amedium',
          method: 'GET',

Error: 

   body: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang=en>↵  <meta charset=utf-8>↵  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">↵  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>↵  <style>↵    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}↵  </style>↵  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>↵  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>↵  <p>The requested URL <code>/analytics/v3/data/realtime/ids=ga%(my_id)&amp;metrics=rt%3AactiveUsers&amp;dimensions=rt%3Amedium</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>↵"
headers:
content-length: "1662"
content-type: "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
date: "Tue, 16 Feb 2021 20:30:23 GMT"
server: "ESF"
__proto__: Object
result: false
status: 404
statusText: null
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: hi, was there an error from the call?

Comment: Hello, I have attached the error. It is reading as a 404 error so there is something wrong with the path name I assume